# Discord.py - how to detect if a user mentions/pings the bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I am just wondering, how can I create an event in discord.py where if a user pings the bot it will respond with a message?

I have not found anything concrete anywhere on how to do this and I would appreciate it if someone could help get my feet wet on how to do this. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 7):

I found that the default function [`discord.User.mentioned_in`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.mentioned_in) works

In order for it to check for our bot, we add `client.user` (which is our bot) in front of the function, making it `client.user.mentioned_in(message)`. The argument `message`, should be the same argument that you gave for the `async def on_message(message)` line

Example:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if client.user.mentioned_in(message):
        await message.channel.send('You mentioned me!')
```

I'm not sure why but I haven't seen any others use this function though. Maybe they just aren't aware of this, and instead use `client.user.id in message.content`

Comment: Hi :), could you add a little description to your answer?

Comment: I felt it was self explanatory, but sure

Answer (score 3):

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    mention = f'<@!{bot.user.id}>'
    if mention in message.content:
        await message.channel.send("You mentioned me")
```

Comment: This code might break if Discord mention strings ever change. I reccomend using the built-in ```user.mention```

Answer (score 3):

Some thing that I found to work was:

```
if str(client.user.id) in message.content:
     await message.channel.send('You mentioned me!')
```

Answer (score 1):

Discord pings in pure text are done with special strings. Luckily you don't have to generate these yourself as discord.py has `user.mention` ([documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.mention)). Your clientuser has this too [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.mention). So we just get the string of our own mention via `client.user.mention`

Now we just have to check if this particular string is in the message:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if client.user.mention in message.content.split():
        await message.channel.send('You mentioned me!')
```

Comment: This code runs fine without raising any errors, but when you actually ping the bot it doesn't send anything. I added ```await client.process_commands(message)``` at the end of the function's code to make sure it ran properly and even then it doesn't. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: @z1234556631 await client.process_commands(message) always also checks for the prefix of your bot, meaning unless your prefix is the mention of the bot it will never trigger. If you want to know how to still have commands invoked open a new question with exactly this.