# How would I go about getting my Discord Python bot to start picking up responses?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So, my idea is that I want the member to do something like "n!guessnumber" and then the bot responds with "OK I am thinking of a number from one to ten." then after, they guess the number and see if they got it right, if they did the bot would respond so but I have no idea how to let the bot respond like that, think anyone could help me out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py - how to detect if a user mentions/pings the bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61243162/discord-py-how-to-detect-if-a-user-mentions-pings-the-bot)

Comment: No, it doesn't ;-;

Comment: You can do this with `wait_for` https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mess = await Bot.wait_for('message')
if mess.author == the_user_who_wanted_to_guess_the_number:
    if mess.content == random.randint(1, 10):
        mess.reply("You guessed right!")
    else:
        mess.reply("Lets try another time...")
```

This should work.

### Bot.wait_for

It's used instead of events into the commands.
For example, if the needed event was "`on_message`", you just have to remove "on_" and pass it as parameter.
Remember that it's a `coroutine` and that you must await it.
Example:

```
Message = await Bot.wait_for("message")
```